# Install quill's source

Tags: javascript, installation, quill

Sorry for this "basic" question but I'm not familliar with javascript APIs. I know there's a Quill CDN but I like to have my website all-centralized so I want to install the package on my server.

I just wanted to know : do I need ALL the files contained in the source zip ? Or do I need to push only some of them on my server to get it fully working ? Is there specific folder structure I have to respect ?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you want the best answers to your questions, please frame them according to these guides: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask & https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve > For a question like yours, we all want to know what you tried and what didn't work for you.

Comment: I don't know where to begin with it, that's why I'm here. Did you seriously block me from asking questions just for that ?

Comment: My only role is to welcome you and provide some guidance on how to use this forum. I'm not sure if nor how nor by whom you were blocked. The question remains, what have you tried that didn't work? When you look through the source code, what do you discern must be uploaded? Have you read the documentation? https://quilljs.com/docs/download/

Comment: That's weird. I'm blocked, I get a condescending message that says that my questions were useless so I can't ask any other question.
I've red the doc and I didn't see any paragraph mentionning the files. I know that I could just copy the fiolder on my server and link the same files called in the snippets in the doc but I'm wondering if these are the only files needed of if there are some that are optionnal.
So what I'm telling you is that, basically, I didn't try anything yet because I don't know where to start from.

Comment: It really depends on what parts you are using in your page, so start including all files, and when the example works, test what parts can be removed. Usually you refer to the minified files (`quill.min.js`), so you don't need the original files (`quill.js`), or sometimes you need only the smaller core files, or don't need the themed css files.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the `quill.js` or event better `quill.min.js` file that is hosted on the CDN and call it locally in your project, hosted on your servers next to your regular other javascript files.